# Clear local storage for div on radio selection

Tags: javascript, radio-button, local-storage

I'm trying to get local storage to clear for all fields in one specific div when the user selects the No radio button:

Slightly incomplete [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m2ax0nLp/2/) but should do the trick

I'm obviously not doing something right here (`.hide-show-yes` is where I want all fields inside that div to clear):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('input[name="for_person"]').on('click', function () {
    if ($('#personNo').prop('checked')) {
    // ??
        $('.hide-show-yes').localStorage.removeItem('fname');

    } else {

        // do nothing

    }
});
});
```

Comment: LocalStorage is not on a per element basis unless you have some jQuery plugin that does some magic..

Comment: The values are being stored for me (see JS fiddle). Thanks.

Comment: Well I would, but your fiddle does not run... `Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined` and `$('.hide-show-yes').localStorage` is still not built into jQuery core.

Comment: @bunnycode Note also, jsfiddle does not appear to permit `.localStorage` access , at least here; try using plnkr plnkr.co to demonstrate `js` utilizing `localStorage`

Answer (score 1):

`localStorage` is not a jQuery method . Also

```
$(document).ready([function() {

    if (localStorage["dontclear"]) {
      $('#dontclear').val(localStorage["dontclear"]);
    }
    if (localStorage["fname"]) {
      $('#fname').val(localStorage["fname"]);
    }
    if (localStorage["lname"]) {
      $('#lname').val(localStorage["lname"]);
    }
  console.log(localStorage)
}, function() {
  $('.stored').change(function() {
    localStorage[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).val();
    console.log(localStorage)
  });

  $('input[name="for_person"]').on('click', function() {
    if ($('#personNo').prop('checked')) {
      // ??
      localStorage.removeItem('fname');

    } else {

      // do nothing

    }
  });
}]);
```

plnkr http://plnkr.co/edit/LPw3zbpgrhJkSh1hdKXG?p=info

Comment: Thank you SO much, that was exactly what I was looking for!