# How to keep input and page the same using local storage

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

Hi I wrote a code which has a working search with filters applied to it. The only problem I am having is that it doesn't stay the same as to how the filters where set when the user closes or refreshes the webpage. I am not using a checkbox

This is my code so far

```js
saveTask: function(name, isCompleted) {
window.localStorage.setItem(name, isCompleted);
 },
 renderTasks: function() {
 for (var i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length; i++) {
  var taskName = window.localStorage.key(i);
  var isCompleted = window.localStorage.getItem(taskName) == "true";
  var taskHTML = Todo.template.replace("<!-- TASK_NAME -->", taskName);

  if (!isCompleted) {
    Todo.container.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', taskHTML);
   }
  }
 }
```

This is a js fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/4p8awnqx/6/
I am trying to keep the filters the same using local storage so that when it is closed or refreshed it stays the same

Comment: See [Global Variable usage on page reload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29986657/global-variable-usage-on-page-reload/)

Comment: can you please show me with my code because I am new to web designing

Comment: How is `javascript` related to `html` at Question?

Comment: Have you tried sessionstorage?

Comment: I want to use local storage and I am not sure how to make it work

Comment: Anyone help????

Comment: @cars Use `change` event, see [Clear local storage for div on radio selection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34618369/clear-local-storage-for-div-on-radio-selection/)